# How to pass struct from Lua to Pascal

Tags: lua, freepascal, lua-table

I have Lua tables that have to pass data to Pascal.
Below is the method that I'm currently using.

**Lua Code:**

```
local ffi=require("ffi")
ffi.cdef[[
void __cdecl Print(char * S);
void __cdecl Func1(struct structLIST *struct1);
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct structLIST {

    int val1;
    char* val2;
    } structLIST1;
#pragma pack(8) 
]]

local str=ffi.new("char[?]",1000)
local tableIndex = {}
local strVal

local valStr= "Enter in loop"

for k,v in pairs(TABLE1) do
    tableIndex=v
    local outRes = ffi.new("structLIST1[1]")

        for k2, v2 in pairs(tableIndex) do

            ffi.copy(str, valStr)
            ffi.C.Print(str)

            if k2=='val1' then                          
                    outRes[0].val1= tonumber(v2)  

            elseif k2=='val2' then 
                    outRes[0].val2= ffi.string(v2) 

            end         
    end 
            ffi.C.Print(str)]]

end
```

**Pascal Code:**

```
type
        TSTRUCT_RECORD = packed record
                             val1:integer;
                             val2 : PChar;
    end;                                                                
procedure Print( S : PChar); public; cdecl;
procedure Func1(p:TSTRUCT_RECORD); public; cdecl;

procedure Print(S: PChar); public; cdecl;
var str:string;
begin

  frmLua.Memo.Lines.Append(S);
end;
procedure Func1(p:TSTRUCT_RECORD);public; cdecl;
var obj:TLIST_RECORD;
begin
  obj.ID:=p.ID;
  obj.ID1:=p.ID1;
end;
```

When the program is run, I get "Enter" once. The  table `TABLE1` has 6 components. Why is the struct not received in Pascal? Thanks!